# How to align negative values and positive values in tables?

Tags: r, shiny, html-table

I'm trying to create a well-formatted correlation matrix table with negative and positive values aligned. It would be great if there is a way to add whitespace before the positive values so that we can left-align them. But I'm stuck. Ideally I would like to achieve it with just tableOutput for shiny, but if there are other packages, I'm open to that as well.

Code

```
corstars <-function(x, method=c("pearson", "spearman"), removeTriangle=c("upper", "lower"),
                     result=c("none", "html", "latex")){
    #Compute correlation matrix
    require(Hmisc)
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    correlation_matrix<-rcorr(x, type=method[1])
    R <- correlation_matrix$r # Matrix of correlation coeficients
    p <- correlation_matrix$P # Matrix of p-value 
    
    ## Define notions for significance levels; spacing is important.
    mystars <- ifelse(p < .001, "*** ", ifelse(p < .01, "**  ", ifelse(p < .05, "*   ", "    ")))
    
    ## trunctuate the correlation matrix to two decimal
    R <- format(round(cbind(rep(-1.11, ncol(x)), R), 2))[,-1]
    
    ## build a new matrix that includes the correlations with their apropriate stars
    Rnew <- matrix(paste(R, mystars, sep=""), ncol=ncol(x))
    diag(Rnew) <- paste(diag(R), " ", sep="")
    rownames(Rnew) <- colnames(x)
    colnames(Rnew) <- paste(colnames(x), "", sep="")
    
    ## remove upper triangle of correlation matrix
    if(removeTriangle[1]=="upper"){
      Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
      Rnew[upper.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
      Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew)
    }
    
    ## remove lower triangle of correlation matrix
    else if(removeTriangle[1]=="lower"){
      Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
      Rnew[lower.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
      Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew)
    }
    
    ## remove last column and return the correlation matrix
    Rnew <- cbind(Rnew[1:length(Rnew)-1])
    if (result[1]=="none") return(Rnew)
    else{
      if(result[1]=="html") print(xtable(Rnew), type="html")
      else print(xtable(Rnew), type="latex") 
    }
}
```

```
corstars(mtcars)
```

This is rmarkdown output.
[image]

[Source for corstars function.](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/elegant-correlation-table-using-xtable-r-package)

Comment: One naive option could be to add a white space in front of every positive value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/render-dt-show-whitespace/70161) to keep white spaces in a rendered table.

```
ui = fluidPage( tags$style("#mytable { white-space:pre; }"), dataTableOutput("mytable") )

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
    corstars(mtcars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```